# What are good GraphQL query patterns?

Tags: graphql

What is a good pattern for GraphQL queries?

Consider the following (`id` and `email` are guaranteed unique).

First a pattern where the query name tells you what argument to expect:

```
getUserById(id)
getUserByEmail(email)
```

vs a single query that can handle either variable:

```
getUser({ id })
getUser({ email })
```

In this scenario, the resolver would pick the field and query by that.

Some of the pros/cons:

- pro: using one query for both types enables more flexibility down the line to add more fields rather than creating new queries for each.
- pro: using one query makes it easier to understand vs hunting different interfaces.
- pro: if the consumer wanted to dynamically change the type you wouldn't have to write another query entirely.
- con: validation would have to be handled manually in the resolver.
- con: the backend complexity for the resolvers is increased.

Answer (score 1):

I have some similar queries in a project and I tend to use the second pattern. Since I use the [knex](https://knexjs.org/) orm my resolver complexity doesn't increase. Just:

```
getUser: (parent,args,context) => knex('user').where(args).first()
```

Thanks to the GraphQL query definition I can depend on the args being limited to certain keys with specific types.

```
query getUser(id: ID, email: emailType): User
```

For args where the results are guaranteed unique this is fine. If the args might yield a non-unique answer then you may wish to handle them differently. There's also the issue of what to do if `id` and `email` don't point to the same record in your case.

Then of course since both `id` and `email` are optional there's the diminutive case where no argument is provided at all. GraphQL doesn't provide a way to specify *at least one* argument must be provided. Each argument is required or not individually.

You may want to handle this differently if you're not personally writing both the resolvers and the client side queries since random clients may send queries that violate your assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

If you can have a query by `id` as the default pattern for all objects and for any special case there will be a descriptive query name.

This takes care of 90% of your need through the default pattern.
Just make an exception when you needed.

```
getUser(id)
getUserByEmail(email)

getCompany(id)
getCompanyByName(name)
```

```js
@Query(() => UserDto, { description: 'Get other user info' })
  async user(@UserDecorator() currentUser: User, @Args('id') id: string) {
  return await this.prisma.user.findUnique({ where: { id } });
}

@Query(() => UserDto, { description: 'Get other user info by Email' })
  async userByEmail(@UserDecorator() currentUser: User, @Args('email') email: string) {
  return await this.prisma.user.findUnique({ where: { email } });
}
```

Alternatively, as mentioned already, pass in all variables as optional and let the backend handle it.

```js
// everything is optional, and each unique
@InputType()
export class UserWhereUniqueInput implements Partial<User> {
  @Field(() => ID, { nullable: true })
  id?: string;

  @Directive('@lowercase')
  @Field(() => String, { nullable: true })
  email?: string;

  @Directive('@lowercase')
  @Field(() => String, { nullable: true })
  username?: string;
}
 
// on the backend, just let the ORM take the input as received
async user(userWhereUniqueInput: UserWhereUniqueInput): Promise<User | null> {
  return this.prisma.user.findUnique({ where: userWhereUniqueInput });
}
```

**Reference:**
https://github.com/neekware/fullerstack

https://github.com/neekware/fullerstack/blob/916cf1031af0e077d339a3fbdad04eeb32fc3884/libs/nsx-user/src/lib/user.model.ts#L155

https://github.com/neekware/fullerstack/blob/916cf1031af0e077d339a3fbdad04eeb32fc3884/libs/nsx-user/src/lib/user.resolver.ts#L64

https://github.com/neekware/fullerstack/blob/916cf1031af0e077d339a3fbdad04eeb32fc3884/libs/nsx-user/src/lib/user.service.ts#L40